# Вывести всё время в сутках

Tags: php

Надо вывести время в формате 23:41, я это сделал, как можно упростить код?

Из-за того, что PHP **00** превращает в **0**, пришлось создавать дополнительные переменные.

```
$h = 0;
    $h2 = 0;
    $m = 0;
    $m2 = 0;
    $hour = 0;

    function foo() {
        global $hour;
        global $h;
        global $h2;
        global $m;
        global $m2;

        for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {
            if($hour < 10) {
                if($m2 < 10) {
                    echo $h . $hour . ':' . $m . $m2;
                    $m2++;
                }


                else {
                    echo $h . $hour . ':' . $m2;
                    $m2++;
                }
            }

            else {
                if($m2 < 10) {
                    echo $hour . ':' . $m . $m2;
                    $m2++;
                }

                else {
                    echo $hour . ':' . $m2;
                    $m2++;
                }
            }

            echo '<br>';

            if($i == 59) {
                $hour++;    
            }
        }

        $m = 0;
        $m2 = 0;
    }

    for($k = 0; $k < 24; $k++) {
        echo foo();
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: а чем вас штатные инструменты не устроили?

Comment: такой же функции нету

Comment: ну обычно так и пишут.... только вместо создания переменной для рисования нуля, просто прилепливают ноль перед переменной

Comment: @DivMan а разве это не та, что вам требуется: `date('H:i');` ?

Comment: Почему Вы предпочитаете глобальные переменные параметрам функции?

Comment: мне так нравится

Answer (score 4):

если хочется вручную сделать то может как то так попроще?

```
for($i=0; $i< 24*60; $i++){
    $h = $i / 60;
    $m = $i % 60;
    printf("%02d:%02d\n", $h, $m);
}
```

*зы: если надо в переменную сохранить, то есть `sprintf`. Если не нравятся эти функции, то можно строку дополнить до нужной длины с помощью `str_pad($h, 2, '0')`, например, и т.п.*

Comment: вот так получилось * $noon = '';
* 
* $h = 0;
* $m = 0;
* 
* while($noon != '23:60') {
* 
* for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {
*  echo str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
*  $m++;
*  $noon = str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
*  echo '<br>';
* }
*  
*  $h++;
*  $i=0;
*  $m=0;
* }
*

Comment: <!-- language: lang-php --> 
 $noon = '';
 
 $h = 0;
 $m = 0;
 
 while($noon != '23:60') {
 
 for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {
  echo str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $m++;
  $noon = str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  echo '<br>';
 }
  
  $h++;
  $i=0;
  $m=0;
 }

Comment: $noon = '';    $h = 0;

Comment: Почему бы админам не сделать форму, к которой есть только кнопка обзора, для загрузки html формы с комментарием, что бы оставить комментарий?

Comment: ## Текст Заголовка ##

Comment: Зачем сначала умножать, чтобы потом поделить, потеряв точность и тип? Не надо так.

Comment: @Mrak вы серьезно думаете, что это принципиально в данной задаче? обратили бы лучше внимание на свой код

Comment: @DivMan `Почему бы админам не сделать форму, к которой есть только кнопка обзора, для загрузки html формы с комментарием, что бы оставить комментарий?` - потому что комментарии эм..... сюрприз.... для комментариев!   Почему бы тебе не взять и не сохранить в песочнице код и не вставить ссылку, раз уж на то пошло

Answer (score 1):

```
for($h = 0; $h < 24; $h++){ // 24 часа
    for($m = 0; $m < 60; $m++){ // по 60 минут
        echo sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $m);
    }
}
```

Comment: вот есть у вас 2 переменных по сути часы и минуты, на на кой черт вы их называете `$i` и `$j`, почему не `$h` и `$m`, кто вам в голову вдолбил, что раз цикл дак сразу `i,j,k`. переменные должны иметь осмысленное название, и в этой задаче оно очевидно должно быть. Зачем использовать `echo sprintf` если `printf` делает то же самое. И `%2d` как ни странно не выведет вам `01:01` он сделает ` 1: 1`, что автору не надо.

Comment: Внёс косметические правки. sprintf нужен на случай заполнения массива.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу другой вариант - воспользоваться классом `DateTime`:

```
function getTime($hour, $min, $fmt = "H:i") {
  $time = new DateTime("$hour:$min");
  return $time->format($fmt);
}

echo getTime(3, 9)."\n";            // 03:09
```

Плюс в том, что при желании можно сменить формат, например, на 12ч с am/pm

```
echo getTime(13, 58, "h:i a")."\n"; // 01:58 pm
```